# TYPO3 7.6.18 - Hide link text

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

I have the following condition for a link. If the linked page is hidden there will be no link. That's fine!

```
<f:if condition="{data_item.tx_mask_link}">
    <f:link.typolink parameter="{data_item.tx_mask_link}">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </f:link.typolink>
</f:if>
```

Is it also possible to hide

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
```

by the condition if the linked page is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You can use {data.hidden} for check out whether page is hidden or not. Let me give you straight example:

```
<f:if condition="{data_item.tx_mask_link}">
    <f:link.typolink parameter="{data_item.tx_mask_link}">
        <f:if condition="{data.hidden}!=0">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
        </f:if>
    </f:link.typolink>
</f:if>
```

Here, check basic stuff {data_item.tx_mask_link} then if {data.hidden} not hidden then shows icon

Greetings!

Comment: When I insert the second condition '<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>' is always hidden. Maybe because the current page is checked and not the linked page?

Comment: Of course it will be hidden if you write inside the condition. You want to show the icon if page is hidden?

Comment: I want to show the icon only if the linked page is not hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. With '<f:if condition="{data.hidden}!=0">' the icon is never shown, with '<f:if condition="{data.hidden}!=1">' always.

Comment: I debuged the variable {data.hidden}. It's always '0', even if the linked page is hidden.